# Which parts can I use to connect a cross axle to a car body?

Tags: wheel

I have some wheels that are connected to cross axles. The wheels don't turn on the axles (they have an X-shaped centre whole ). Which parts can be used to Connect the axle to the car body? It's supposed to be a very basic car for my 4 year old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give many details, but there are cross-axle to round-axle pegs available, or you can put the cross-axle through a round-axle brick.

[image]

Comment: thnx , exactly whar i needed